# ThreeJS r59 Traverse of null objects

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I have a MTLLoader along side with UTF8Loader and i recently updated my project from r57 to r59. It solved some memory leaks but now i have a big problem.

the traverse function is throwing an error on three-min.js about cannot call traverse of null.

I guess this new revision are messing with me. The code is the same that runs fine with r57.

Look at this pseudo code:

```
var callback = function (object) {
    object.traverse(function (node) {
        // code here
    });
};

new THREE.UTF8Loader().load('myUrl', callback , { normalizeRGB: true, textureFilter: 0 });
```

In the very first time the code reachs the callback, it throws de error about cannot call traverse of null. My guess is that it's something with object's children.

Anyone have any insights/thoughts?
Regards

Comment: Use `three.js` for testing, not `three.min.js`. Step through it with the debugger.

Comment: any luck? I'm having the same problem